# Python: How to print just one line within a loop

Tags: python

I'm just trying to simply override an error in my program and I've used the try and except function. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('fake.csv') as csvfile:
    sched = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in sched:
        a = row[1]
        try:
            if (a == sys.argv[1]):
                print(row)
        except Exception:
            print("Sorry. Try again.")
```

This did work but instead of printing out just one line, it reprinted in accordance to my csv file that has 6 lines so it printed out:

```
Sorry. Try again.
Sorry. Try again.
Sorry. Try again.
Sorry. Try again.
Sorry. Try again.
Sorry. Try again.
```

I understand that it's because it's from being within the loop but it's due to the csv file needing to be a loop in order to print the right conclusion. Is there any way I can print just one line saying "Sorry Try again when any input doesn't match anything in the csv.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please write code using a code block so it is display with a monospaced font to improve readability. Also please add correct indentation, as the code is not syntactically correct.

Comment: The try/except doesn't seem to be doing anything useful here. The only exception I could see it catching is if no argument was supplied on the command line. That must have happened in order for you to get the output you got, in which case no edits to break out the loop would be useful anyway. You should try to solve errors instead of ignoring them because ignoring them will make your program work incorrectly no matter what else you do.

Answer (score 1):

Svrem's solution does exactly as you ask and I've voted it up on that basis - however from experience, having a singular error message on trying to read in a csv file is not very useful. What you'll likely end up wanting is some guidance on which lines are bad. I'd suggest something along the lines of the following:

```
import csv
import sys

badLines = []
with open('fake.csv') as csvfile:
    sched = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    
    iRows = 1  #iRows is a counter for the current row in the CSV we are on
    for row in sched:
        a = row[1]
        
        #Below is edited to amend nonsensical code (which is in source) as pointed out by Kemp
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            if (a == sys.argv[1]):
                print(row)
            else:
                badLines.append(iRows)  
        else:
            print("Are you missing a command line argument to this function?")

        iRows = iRows + 1  

if badLines:
    print("bad line entries in CSV found, these are")
    print(badLines)  #You could of course wrap this into the one print statement, but this is a simple and clear solution, so why bother
```

Comment: What exactly is the try/except doing here? The only exception I can see it catching is an `IndexError` accessing `sys.argv`, which has nothing to do with the csv rows.

Comment: Without knowing what is in the csv file, it looks like its comparing the 2nd entry in each row of the csv file to an argument passed in to this function when called from the command line. If they match, then good, if not, its a problem.

I'd *guess* that its perhaps looking to ensure consistency of data.

Comment: Except a mismatch wouldn't throw an exception. As I said, the only exception it would catch is an `IndexError` if the user forgot to supply a command line argument. The fact that it was phrased as "trying to override an error in my program" makes me think that's exactly what happened and instead of trying to figure out why they got the exception, they just stuck a try/except in there to get rid of it and still didn't give the required argument.

Comment: Good point. Will rejig to at least be coherent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a break statement. This will break the loop.

So in your case it would be:

```
import csv

import sys

with open('fake.csv') as csvfile:

    sched = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in sched:

        a = row[1]

        try:

            if (a == sys.argv[1]):

                print(row)

        except Exception:

            print("Sorry. Try again.")
            break
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the question asked. They want a message to be printed if the supplied string doesn't match *anything* in the csv, not to print it and exit the loop the first time it encounters something that doesn't match. See also my other comments about how the try/except is probably not what they want either.

Comment: Kemp, I'm sorry my answer didn't suit you. But OP didn't ask for fancy work arounds for the try statement. He (in my opinion) asked for a way to only print out once. So my solution is exactly what he wanted. Again in my opinion.

Comment: From the question: "Is there any way I can print just one line saying "Sorry Try again when any input **doesn't match anything in the csv**." Your solution doesn't do the "doesn't match" part at all, it checks if the user entered an argument at the command line. In your solution, printing the message *doesn't have anything to do with matches*. Even if it was checking for matches (which, I will stress, it isn't), your solution would print the message and exit the first time something doesn't match, rather than if nothing matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers are answering the wrong thing by tweaking the code you have. The `try/except` isn't doing what you want it to do. The only exception it will catch is an `IndexError` if you forget to supply an argument on the command line, which isn't what you described using it for.

If you want to show the message only if there were no matching rows then you need to track the matching row count, e.g.:

```
import csv
import sys

count = 0

with open('fake.csv') as csvfile:
    sched = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in sched:
        if (row[1] == sys.argv[1]):
            print(row)
            count += 1

if count == 0:
    print("Sorry, try again.")
```